# R dbReadTable returns no such table error

Tags: r, sqlite, dbi, rsqlite

I ran this bit of code yesterday successfully, but today, I am getting a 'no such table' error. I am trying to pull data in a table (named tblLatjamInputs) from an SQLite database into R using `DBI::dbReadTable()`, but it is acting as though the table does not exist.

Using SQLiteStudio

[image: screenshot of SQLiteStudio showing the existence of the table]

and separately the command line

[image: screenshot of command line window showing that table exists in the database]

[image],

I can see that the table does indeed exist and that there are data in the table.

Here is the code, both written out and as a screenshot so you can see the error I'm getting.

```
setwd("D:/hsm/databases")
db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), conn = "lookup_and_tracking.sqlite")
tblName <- "tblLatjamInputs"
df.full <- dbReadTable(db, tblName)
```

```
Error in result_create(conn@ptr, statement) : no such table: tblLatjamInputs
```

I got the same error when the `tblName` line is changed to this: `tblName <- dbQuoteIdentifier(db, "tblLatjamInputs")`

[image: screenshot of code in R to retrieve table information from an sqlite database and the resulting error]

`dbListTables(db)` returns `character(0)`, and `dbListFields(db, "lkpSpecies")` (a different table in the db) returns the no such table error as well.

I checked that there are no spaces around the table name in the database. I also tried to pull data from other tables (to see if it was just an issue with this table), but I got the same error. I have tried disconnecting and reconnecting to the database multiple times, including disconnecting from the db, closing SQLiteStudio and the command line, and then reopening. I also tried closing everything, including R, reloading the project, and starting again from scratch. I also tried connecting to a different database altogether with the same results (R makes the connection, but can't seem to find any tables). I'm totally baffled because, as I mentioned, all this works fine in the command line, and I did this yesterday with the same database, table, and lines of code, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
db <- dbConnect(SQLite(), "lookup_and_tracking.sqlite")
```

The problem is the file name parameter is not named `conn=`; It's `dbname=` and the default is `""` which creates a new, empty data base.

Comment: Aha! I don't know how that `conn = ` snuck in there between yesterday and today, but that did the trick. Thank you!